# How to move items between two vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, move-semantics

Is there any way how to move several items from one std::vector to another without using Copy Constructor?

Consider the following test code

```
class CTest
{
public:
    int m_value;
    CTest(int n) : m_value(n) {}
    CTest(CTest&& mv) { m_value = mv.m_value; }
    CTest(const CTest& cp) = delete;
};

    std::vector< CTest> vct1;
    vct1.emplace_back(CTest(1));

    //Now move items from vct1 to vct2 to specified position
    std::vector< CTest> vct2;

    //Error: 'CTest &CTest::operator =(const CTest &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
    vct2.insert(vct2.begin(), std::make_move_iterator(vct1.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(vct1.end()));

    //Error: CTest &CTest::operator =(const CTest &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
    std::move(vct1.begin(), vct1.end(), vct2.begin());
    std::move(vct1.begin(), vct1.end(), std::inserter(vct2, vct2.begin()));
```

The only working thing is to use back_inserter which probably internally using emplace_back:

```
//This works
std::move(vct1.begin(), vct1.end(), std::back_inserter(vct2));
```

But I would need to insert new items also to the front or in the middle of vector.

I don't want to add it one-by-one because of vector reallocation. Is there any other way? Or should I manually create a new vector, preallocate it to the target size and manually move it one-by-one?

Thanks

Comment: Add move assignment operator, `CTest& operator=(CTest&&)`, then all lines will compile fine.

Comment: BTW: std::vector is maybe the wrong container. For moving things arround you should think of using some linked list types.

Comment: @rafix07: Thanks! I focused so much on the minimal test case and on reported errors that I forgot to add it. It's working now ;-)

Comment: @Klaus: It's a minimal test case. In the real app it's boost::stable_vector used because of very fast access speed and permanent iterators with very occasional data merge

Comment: @rafix07 Please add it as the answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @rafix07, although the error was

```
'CTest &CTest::operator =(const CTest &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

the problem was in missing move assign operator

```
CTest& operator=(CTest&& mv) { m_value = mv.m_value; return *this; }
```

After that, all three mentioned methods works:

```
vct2.insert(vct2.begin(), std::make_move_iterator(vct1.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(vct1.end()));
std::move(vct1.begin(), vct1.end(), std::inserter(vct2, vct2.begin()));
std::move(vct1.begin(), vct1.end(), std::back_inserter(vct2));
```